# How can I change my tmux color scheme based on the time of day?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I just implemented a few lines into my .vimrc that changes the color scheme from SolarizedDark to SolarizedLight based on the time of day.

```
" Solarized light during the day, solarized dark during the night
let hour = strftime("%H")
if 6 <= hour && hour < 18
  set background=light
else
  set background=dark
endif
```

Is it possible to do this for tmux and OS X terminal as well?

Comment: The way I'd approach this is by having a program that changes colors for everything depending on the time of the day? (such as "f.lux" for windows/linux/etc, but many other exist). That way everything is consistent and is back to normal if you look that same thing at a daytime hour later.

Answer (score 1):

Not readily at the level of `tmux` or OSX Terminal (`tmux`'s scripting does not appear powerful enough), but if you happen to be using `bash`, it has a feature called the prompt-command into which you can put scripts.

Here are some pointers (with examples):

- [Bash Prompt HOWTO: 4.1. PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html)
- [What is the difference between PS1 and PROMPT_COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058325/what-is-the-difference-between-ps1-and-prompt-command)
- [ArchLinux: Color Bash Prompt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt)

If you happen to be using `zsh`, it seems that offers possibilities as well:

- [Steve Losh: My Extravagant Zsh Prompt](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/)
- [How to Customize Your Command Prompt](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-command-prompt--net-24083)

The key point in all of these is that some shells provide the ability to invoke general-purpose scripts each time the prompt is displayed.

Comment: Something running as a background shell job can keep updating the color even if the prompt is not displayed, but in this way output from other programs have chances to mix up with the job.

Comment: Sure - but the choices in that case would be to apply the color scheme only to the prompt, or just live with other applications' notion of colors.  Since you keep returning to the prompt, though, that's a place to keep resetting colors, to enforce it.  Not 100% reliable as you note.